# How to show ellipse on the bottom of the div

Tags: html, css

I want to have an sort of ellipse on the bottom of the div, but I want that it is responsive.  I have next code:

```css
.home-title {
  background-color: #ba173a;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-title:before { 
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -95px;
  left: 33%;
  margin-left: -939px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 2050px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 100px solid #fff;

}

.g-font-weight-600{
  font-weight: 600;
}

.g-pa-70{
  padding: 70px;
}

.g-color-white{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-title">
  <h2 class="g-font-weight-600 g-pa-70 g-color-white">
    This is some dummy text<br />This is more dummy text
  </h2>
</div>
```

The problem in this snippet is that I always need to change `width` in `.home-title:before` get it right.

Any idea how can I be able to always have an ellipse on the bottom of the div no matter what the screen size is.

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kbovxgtf/)

**UPDATE**

I want that effect at the divs corners

[image]
[image]

And not that effect:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the exact specs? Be definition, an infinite amount of ellipses are possible. Does it have to have a specific ratio? Enclose the `<h2>` (and how)? Please be specific. My initial guess would be: use an image with adaptative width, but I'm not sure it's the kind of answers you want.

Comment: What do you mean by ellipsis? Is'nt that the property we use in text-overflow?

Comment: @ThanveerShah No. Check the fiddle.

Comment: **Ellipsis** is the three dots use to show more text is coming.... **Ellipse** is the curve

Comment: So you want that small shape to be seen in every device?

Comment: @ThanveerShah Check the fiddle and try to resize it and you will see that the ellipse effect doesn't look good.

Comment: Understood, I can fix this

Comment: Check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then this can be achieved by creating a psuedo element that:

1. has a `border-radius` set to `100%`. This causes the curvature to responsively adapt to the box boundary of the pseudo element (what ever it may be)
2. set the pseudo element's width to `100%`
3. set the height to a fixed amount, where a shallow height creates a pseudo element with a "rectangular boundary". This will create the region in which the ellipse/curved shape along the bottom edge of the parent element will be defined.
4. vertically offset the pseudo element from the bottom edge of the parent, by half the pseudo element's height. This causes the bottom half of the pseudo element to be visible to produce the illusion of the curved bottom edge on the parent element
5. color the pseudo elements background color to match that of the parent:

```css
.home-title {
  background-color: #ba173a;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-title:before { 
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display:block;
        
  /* Color of curve to match parent background color */
  background:#ba173a;  

  /* Causes the curve/radius to adaptively resize based on parent width */
  border-radius: 100%;       

  /* Causes curve to expand adaptively to parent width */
  width: 100%;

  /* Set fixed height to twice that of curve depth */
  height: 100px;

  /* Offset ellipse to create illusion of curve */
  bottom:-50px;

}

.g-font-weight-600{
  font-weight: 600;
}

.g-pa-70{
  padding: 70px;
}

.g-color-white{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-title">
  <h2 class="g-font-weight-600 g-pa-70 g-color-white">
    This is some dummy text<br />This is more dummy text
  </h2>
</div>
```

#### Update

To achieve the "sharp" corners (as shown in updated question) combined with a responsive curved "bottom edge" you could revise you code as follows:

```css
.home-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Add padding to bottom to allow depth of curve to be visible */
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Style nested div */
.home-title>div { 
  background-color: #ba173a;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-title>div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;

  /* Offset the ellipse left-ward by some amount */
  left: -10%;

  /* Set width percentage to exceed the parent width, plus twice the offset amount */
  width: 120%;

  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ba173a;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: -50px;
}

.g-font-weight-600 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.g-pa-70 {
  padding: 70px;
}

.g-color-white {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-title">
  <div> <!-- UPDATE: Add nested element -->
    <h2 class="g-font-weight-600 g-pa-70 g-color-white">
      This is some dummy text<br />This is more dummy text
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8Lm932jv/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not ellipsis, it is a circle.

Comment: @Boky sorry about that - at my end it seems to show an ellipses. Perhaps I've misunderstood your question?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: @Boky does this help? https://jsfiddle.net/Lat3q21h/

Comment: That is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Boky cool - glad I could help. I just updated the answer also :)

Comment: Would [this](/a/54177427/3634538) have worked for you too, @Boky?

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you mean?

```css
.home-title {
  background-color: #ba173a;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}


/*
.home-title:before { 
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -95px;
  left: 33%;
  margin-left: -939px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 2050px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 100px solid #fff;
}
*/

.g-font-weight-600 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.g-pa-70 {
  padding: 70px;
}

.g-color-white {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-title">
  <h2 class="g-font-weight-600 g-pa-70 g-color-white">
    This is some dummy text<br />This is more dummy text
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser but this is not what I want. I said it in the updated question.

Comment: OK, well. Although honestly I can't see the difference between my version and the accepted answer? Except that the accepted one uses separate pseudo element for giving the elliptic look. Anyway, glad you found your answer.

Comment: Check @Dacre's first answer (it is like yours) and then check the updated one.

Comment: Nah, not exactly "like" mine, as I said I did not use any additional pseudo element in achieving the same result. Maybe it's just me.